# Scroll and back button not working in Fragment with CollapsingToolbarLayout in Android 10

Tags: android

I need assistance with two problems, that may be connected:

1. Back button in Toolbar is not working. I set the NavigationOnClickListener on it, but it is not called when I click on the button.
2. Scroll is not working. When I try to scroll the text, nothing happens and the CollapsingToolbar does not collapse.

The issue started happening when the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion were updated from 28 to 29. However, I have no idea why.

Please see code below... Thank you.

MyFragmentContent:

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        androidComponent.inject(this)
        val binding = MyFragmentContentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        arguments?.let {
            val tutorialType = getTutorialType()
            binding.tutorialType = tutorialType
            binding.cardViewTutorial.transitionName = tutorialType.toString()
            binding.recyclerViewContent.adapter = MyContentAdapter(MyDataProvider.getContent(tutorialType, resources, service))
            binding.recyclerViewContent.setHasFixedSize(false)
        }

        val context = binding.recyclerViewContent.context
        val normalDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.arrow_long_nav_left)
        normalDrawable?.let {
            normalDrawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
            binding.toolbar.navigationIcon = normalDrawable
        }

        binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { v -> v.findNavController().navigateUp() }

        return binding.root
    }
```

my_fragment_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="tutorialType"
            type="com.enumeration.TutorialType" />
    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_tutorial"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">


            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:contentScrim="@color/transparent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:title="">

                    <com.myproject.views.CustomTextView
                        style="@style/RegularText"
                        android:background="@drawable/top_bc_lng_tut_green_arc"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_title"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium_medium"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/tutorial_page_title_padding_start"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_medium_medium"
                        android:text="@{tutorialType.textTitle}"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xlarge_medium"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        tools:text="@string/insulin_calc_tutorial_quick_use_title" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:title="" />

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_tutorial_paragraph" />
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the material component to this version and it started working again. Probably was some incompatibility with Android 10.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```